# Use CiviCampaign to send emails to a target?

Tags: civicampaign

We are running a campaign and have used SpeakOut! a wordpress plugin that send emails to a target and signs a petition.  For example Tell XYZ to do X! then it will send an email to XYZ from that person and have them sign the petition.  Can I use CiviCampaign to do something like that?

Many thanks!

Note: Using Latest Wordpress and CiviCRM

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) extension to get that is required. You can setup triggers, conditions and actions using this extension.

A detailed documentation has been compiled by them which can be found [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but this is way too complicated for our needs. I was hoping it would be as simple as creating a petition in CiviCampaign.

Comment: I can imagine your hope, but unfortunately it is not.